# Swing JUI flickering vs lagging?

Tags: java, swing, paint, simulation, game-physics

I am testing basic ball collision in Java. I am doing my painting on JPanel. All the balls are stored in an ArrayList. When the number of balls is low there is no problem. But if the no of balls is high the gui starts lagging. I am using double buffering. The structure of my code is:

```
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{
BufferedImage bi;  //offscreen drawing on this image
/*constructor......end of constructor*/
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
g.drawImage(bi,0,0);
}

//Method draw() for drawing on buffered image
public void draw()
{
 /*
lots of drawing on buffered image
takes about 2-3-4 millliseconds
*/
//now draw this buffered image
this.repaint();
}
```

I have a thread AnimationUpdater which updates collision physics and makes a call to draw()
:

```
public class AnimationUpdater extends Thread{
final DrawingPanel panel;
/*inititializations and various code*/
//run
@Override
public void run()
{
long interval;  /*calculate and store time taken in processing physics and drawing. This is also the time which is used in equations.*/
while(true)
{ 

updatePhysics();
panel.draw();
Thread.sleep(6); //slow things down

}
```

}}
The problem with above scheme is the call to draw method is not in the EventThread and hence makes the screen flicker. The overall time taken in processing between each step of interation is reduced as the number of balls is increased and hence the framerate goes down. But if i call it in a different thread as:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
panel.draw();
}
});
```

Works for fewer balls but The GUI starts to lag after fixed intervals of time as the number of balls is increased. The frame rate also does not go down as the time in drawing operation(2-3-4seconds time) is not consumed because of execution in different thread.
How should i resolve this. please help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  The way those code snippets go about animation is SNAFU.  Use a Swing `Timer` rather that `Thread`/`sleep(n)`

Comment: The code is too long to be posted here.

Comment: *"The code is too long to be posted here."*  Good luck with it.

Comment: *"The problem with above scheme is the call to draw method is not in the EventThread and hence makes the screen flicker."* Then make the call in the Event Thread. For instance using [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)